# Добавление элементов в конец одномерного массива

Tags: массивы, c++

Как записать добавление элементов в конец массива? Используется датчик случайных чисел, все через консоль.Добавляются лишние элементы, и при перестановке один теряется...

**Перенесено из комментария**.

А как это записать? Так-то программа имеет такой вид: только вот правильно ли?

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* Rus(const char* text);

void main()
{
    int a[100];
    int i,n,k,imin,imax,i1(0),i2(0);
    randomize();
    cout << Rus(" Введите n: ");
    cin >> n;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) a[i]=random(100);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) cout << a[i] <<" ";
    cout << Rus(" Удаление всех элементов с четными индексами: ") << endl;
    for( i=0; i<n/2; i++) a[i]=a[i*2+1];
    for( i=0; i<n/2; i++) cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << Rus(" Сколько к элементов хотите добавить в конец массива ? ") << endl;
    cin >> k;
    for(i=n;i<n+k;i++)
    cout << Rus("Массив имеет вид:\n ") << endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) cout << a[i] <<" ";
    n+=k;
    imin=a[0];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    if(a[i]<imin)
    imin=a[i];
    i1=i;
    cout<< " Min "<< imin << endl;
    imax=a[0];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    if(a[i]>imax)
    imax=a[i];
    i2=i;
    cout << " Max "<< imax << endl;
    a[i2]=imin;
    a[i1]=imax;
    cout << Rus("Массив после перестановки имеет вид:\n ")<< endl;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) cout << a[i] <<" ";
    cout << Rus("Первый отрицательный элемент массива: ")<< endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n && a[i] >= 0; i++)a[i]=random(100)-random(100);
    if(i < n)
    cout << a[i] <<" ";
    getch();
    }

char bufRus[256];
char* Rus(const char* text)
{
CharToOem(text,bufRus);
return bufRus;
}
```

Comment: Сколько у Вас всего используется)))
Процедура простая достаточно. Если размерность массива позволяет, то на следующую за последним элементом добавляется ещё один.

Comment: Или используйте vector.

Comment: Постарайтесь, пожалуйста, свою клинопись превратить в нормально записанный код. "k" у Вас не инициализировано. Вам необходимо держать в памяти число "занятых" элементов массива и каждый раз проверять не вышли ли Вы за границы массива.

Comment: @Neon, мыслите в правильном направлении. Для простых типов можно для этого использовать пару функций malloc-realloc из библиотеки Си.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный способ - это std::vector.

```
int n;
std::vector< int > a;

cout << "Input n";
cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a.push_back(rand());
```

Comment: С вектром каждый дурак сможет. Тут интересно все ручками на низком уровне прописать.

Comment: ещё раз про realloc?

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужно использовать динамическое выделение памяти.

```
int* a;
int i, n, k;
randomize();
cout << Rus(" Введите n: ");
cin >> n;
if (n>0) a = new int[n];
else сильно ругаемся и или выходим из программы, или требуем ввести еще раз
```

В конце:

```
delete [] a;
```

Comment: Можно просто объявить массив размером n после ввода значения n.

    cout << Rus(" Введите n: ");
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    ... // Ваши циклы ввода-обработки.

Кстати, матрицы [n][m] тоже работают.

Comment: Да, С++ такое позволяет. Только если n будет очень большим, может стека не хватить.

Comment: gcc тоже. 

Насчет стека - а набивать не устанет ? new тоже NULL может вернуть (точнее видимо какой-нибудь exception (я не знаю этот момент)).

Comment: А кто устанет набивать? Там же массив наполняется случайными числами от random? 

Оперативная память, конечно, не бесконечная. Только стек как правило много меньше всей доступной для кучи памяти. А также при переполнении стека программа просто вылетит, а ноль, возвращенный new, легко отследить и сделать соответстующие сообщения и т.д.

Comment: Действительно, слона-то я и не приметил. Собственно речь ведь была о  том, как выделить память в количестве неизвестном при написании программы.

Comment: Классическая задача

Comment: Я ваще не врубился зачем оно нужно

Comment: >Да, С++ такое позволяет. Только если n будет очень большим, может стека не хватить.

 У меня в VC++ не работает. Это расширение или фича нового стандарта C.

Comment: Можете посмотреть [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/37648/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0)

IMHO еще может потребоваться обработка сигнала и возможно siglongjmp().